# Django extends tag loading wrong templates

Tags: html, django, django-templates, extends

I'm building a new site in Django using TailWind CSS and have been trying to utilize to the use of extends tags and block content.

This is the base.html file:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="{% block description %}{% endblock %}">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="canonical" href=""/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{% static 'css/style.css'%}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">

        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;1,400;1,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- START NAV -->
    <div class="w-full text-gray-700 bg-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 dark-mode:bg-gray-800">
  <div x-data="{ open: false }" class="flex flex-col max-w-screen-xl px-4 mx-auto md:items-center md:justify-between md:flex-row md:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="p-4 flex flex-row items-center justify-between">
      <a href="{% url 'main' %}" class="text-lg font-semibold tracking-widest text-gray-900 uppercase rounded-lg dark-mode:text-white focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">Dummy Logo</a>
      <button class="md:hidden rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" @click="open = !open">
        <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="w-6 h-6">
          <path x-show="!open" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM9 15a1 1 0 011-1h6a1 1 0 110 2h-6a1 1 0 01-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
          <path x-show="open" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
    <nav :class="{'flex': open, 'hidden': !open}" class="flex-col flex-grow pb-4 md:pb-0 hidden md:flex md:justify-end md:flex-row">
      <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="{% url 'main' %}">Home</a>
      <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="">Web Hosting</a>
      <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="{% url 'domain_names' %}">Domain Names</a>
      <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="{% url 'blog' %}">Blog</a>
      <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="{% url 'blog' %}">Sign In</a>
      </div>    
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END NAV -->
       
{% block content %}{% endblock %}

<!--FOOTER-->

<!--END FOOTER-->
        
        <script src= "{% static '/js/script.js' %}" async defer></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the idex.html file:

```
{% extends '../includes/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Index dummy title{% endblock %}
{% block description %}This is a dummy description{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<section class="text-gray-600 body-font">
  <div class="container mx-auto flex px-5 py-24 md:flex-row flex-col items-center">
    <div class="lg:flex-grow md:w-1/2 lg:pr-24 md:pr-16 flex flex-col md:items-start md:text-left mb-16 md:mb-0 items-center text-center">
      <h1 class="title-font sm:text-4xl text-3xl mb-4 font-medium text-gray-900">Before they sold out
        <br class="hidden lg:inline-block">readymade gluten
      </h1>
      <p class="mb-8 leading-relaxed">Copper mug try-hard pitchfork pour-over freegan heirloom neutra air plant cold-pressed tacos poke beard tote bag. Heirloom echo park mlkshk tote bag selvage hot chicken authentic tumeric truffaut hexagon try-hard chambray.</p>
      <div class="flex justify-center">
        <button class="inline-flex text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded text-lg">View Plans</button>
        <button class="ml-4 inline-flex text-gray-700 bg-gray-100 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-200 rounded text-lg">Learn More</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lg:max-w-lg lg:w-full md:w-1/2 w-5/6">
      <img class="object-cover object-center rounded" alt="hero" src="https://dummyimage.com/720x600">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


{% endblock %}
```

This is the domain-names.html file:

```
{% extends '../includes/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Dummy title{% endblock %}
{% block description %}This is a dummy description{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<h1> Domain Heading </h1>


{% endblock %}
```

File tree for template folder is:

```
-template
—app_main
——domain-names.html
——index.html
——web-hosting.html
—includes
——base.html
```

The urls.py file is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main, name="main"),
    path('web-hosting/', views.main, name="web_hosting"),
    path('domain-names/', views.main, name="domain_names"),
]
```

The views file is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def main(request):
    return render(request, 'app_main/index.html', {})

def web_hosting(request):
    return render(request, 'app_main/web-hosting.html', {})

def domain_names(request):
    return render(request, 'app_main/domain-names.html', {})
```

The issue is when I load the domain names page it's showing content from index.html. I think I have over looked something, any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Please post the *filetree*.

Comment: File tree for the template folder is:

File Tree is:

-template
—app_main
——domain-names.html
——index.html
——web-hosting.html
—includes
——base.html

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the clarification there (comments are not great to display file trees and / or code). Plus most of the HTML you added could have been truncated, you should take a look at how to write a [mre].

Comment: I have added it to the question and removed a chunk of the html. I hope that helps, I will read through that page before posting more questions

Comment: @NSqui are you sure you are rendering the correct template? Show your url patterns for the pages you talk about and their views.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have added to urls.py file and views.py to the bottom of the question. I think i've missed something but I just can't work out where

Comment: @NSqui all your patterns use the view `views.main`, you want to specify the view you want to use for the pattern properly e.g. for `web-hosting/` it should be `path('web-hosting/', views.web_hosting, name="web_hosting"),` (notice that instead of `views.main` it is `views.web_hosting`)...

Comment: I just tried that and works perfectly. Thank you, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `urlpatterns` is pointing at `views.main` in both paths, which is why It goes to the wrong page.